# Which home automation standards will work with Apple and/or Google's forthcoming sofware?

Tags: home-automation, software

On one hand I'm happy that Apple and Google are getting into home automation, because the existing software and control apps seem to be uniformly atrocious. On the other hand, I've been planning a big home automation purchase all year, and now I'm nervous because I'm sure their products are going to take over the market and I don't want to get hardware that won't be compatible.

Have there been any announcements about which existing home automation hardware is going to work with Apple and/or Google's software? Are there any standards that are more or less likely to survive?

I'm mostly interested in lighting and generic outlet automation.

Answer (score 2):

All that Google has, from what I know (and googled to double check), is that they own Nest.  They apparently had an "Android @ Home" project a few years ago, but I couldn't find any recent news on it.  Personally I'd bank on Apple moving in on your home before Google-- simply because they already have their framework public, so developers can already start creating apps

https://developer.apple.com/homekit/
http://9to5mac.com/2015/01/22/apple-details-homekit-compatibility-with-competing-home-automation-platforms/

Apple's HomeKit framework will only be compatible with "MFi" (made for iPhone) hardware.

Here is a nice article that recommends some hardware that will already be compatible with HomeKit apps, and claim they should also be "future-proof"

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/future-proofing-smart-home-apple-homekit-compatibility/

Of course all of this also depends on what phone you have as well.